# Assign Custom Band Combination To Image Catalogs In ArcGIS

Tags: arcobjects, raster, imagery, raster-catalog

I have an image catalog composed of 4 band rasters.  I would like to use the same image catalog, and set custom renderers for a true color and false color combination and save each of those catalogs off as a layer file.  In addition I would like to turn off the default stretch for each catalog.  The code I am using is below (where lyr is a reference to a raster catalog):

```
                IRasterCatalogLayer rcl = lyr as IRasterCatalogLayer;

                IRasterRGBRenderer pRGB = new RasterRGBRendererClass();
                IRasterStretch pRasStretch = pRGB as IRasterStretch;
                rcl.Renderer = pRGB as IRasterRenderer;

                pRasStretch.StretchType = esriRasterStretchTypesEnum.esriRasterStretch_NONE;
                int r, g, b;
                pRGB.QueryBandIndices(out r, out g, out b);
                pRGB.UseRedBand = true;
                pRGB.RedBandIndex = 3;
                pRGB.UseGreenBand = true;
                pRGB.GreenBandIndex = 0;
                pRGB.UseBlueBand = true;
                pRGB.BlueBandIndex = 1;

                int r1, g1, b1;
                pRGB.QueryBandIndices(out r1, out g1, out b1);

                rcl.Renderer.Update();
```

The stretch is being applied without problem, but I cannot change the band combinations.  Thoughts?  Is there a better way to do this without resorting to ArcObjects to create layer files.

Comment: Did you try following the steps in [this example](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriCarto/IRasterRGBRenderer_Example.htm) exactly?  If you did and you get different results, I'd say it is a bug.

Comment: I cannot completley follow that example because i am dealing with a IRasterCatalogLayer instead of an IRasterLayer.  The IRasterCatalogLayer does not have a Raster property that I can assign to the new IRasterRenderer.  Now, I suppose I can snag the first raster in the image catalog and use that as a Raster.